# Starting nodejs application on server start gives exit with code 2

Tags: upstart

I'm running the below on server startup:

```
exec sudo -E -u www-data /usr/bin/node /etc/nodeserver/app.js >> /var/log/applicationserver.log 2>&1
```

The console writes many messages that the start exited with the code 2. The application is still started in the end.

Where can I find information about the exit codes for nodejs?

Answer (score 1):

I am not using node.js, so please take this with a grain of salt.

However I looked up [reserved exit codes](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html) for Unix in general, and *Code 2* seems to be similar to Code 1 (general error).

You could try node with a trivial program, and therefore see if it also emits the same row of error messages. It could be the `app.js` that displays these messages. Does node have a man page? It generally includes the exit codes the program uses.

Also I've searched for ways to exit a process in node with an exit code, and the [right way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266152/how-to-exit-in-node-js) to do this seems to be the [process object](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.3.1/api/process.html).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error with `/usr/sbin/node` being used instead of `/usr/bin/node`.
I just removed `/usr/sbin/node`